# onChildAdded is taking too long to start being called

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a chat application which is implemented using Firebase Realtime database entities only. No specific messaging components.

I'm adding a listener for the chat entity (or table) where the messages are stored. The listener is added by addChildEventListener which should call the onChildAdded method to bring all the children from chat entity in the moment it's attached and whenever a message is added.

The problem is that when I create the table, send the first message and attach the listener, I can see the table and message being created on the Firebase console, but the onChildAdded method is not called but a lot of time later. Then, as soon as it is called, sometimes more than 5 minutes later, I'm able to send and receive the messages as expected.

What could be causing this long delay?

I already tried to set the listener right after creating the table it listens to, but didn't work.

**Creating the chat entity (table)**

```
final DatabaseReference chat = dbReference.child("chat");

final DatabaseReference user = dbReference.child("user");

chatId = chat.push().getKey();

Log.d("mymessages", "createChat(), chatId = " + chatId);

HashMap newChatMap = new HashMap();
newChatMap.put("id", chatId);
newChatMap.put("users/" + currentUserId, true);
newChatMap.put("users/" + userId, true);

// Creating chats table
chat.child(chatId)
        .child("info")
        .updateChildren(newChatMap);
Log.d("mymessages", "Chat table created.");
```

**Creating the message and inserting it in the chat entity**

```
DatabaseReference newMessageDb = dbReference.child("chat").child(chatId).push();

Log.d("mymessages", "message created.");

Map newMessageMap = new HashMap<>();
newMessageMap.put("text", editTextMessage);
newMessageMap.put("creator", currentUserId);

newMessageDb.updateChildren(newMessageMap);
Log.d("mymessages", "message's text and creator added.");
```

**Adding the listener**

```
 dbReference.child("chat").child(chatId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

            \\Fetch the messages...

        } else {

            Log.d("mymessages", "fetchChatMessages(), dataSnapshot does not exists.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {                        
    }
});
```

**Entire code that runs inside the button that sends the message**

```
String editTextMessage = messageBodyEditText.getText().toString();

        if (!editTextMessage.isEmpty()) {

            if (!chatExists) {
                final DatabaseReference chat = dbReference.child("chat");
                final DatabaseReference user = dbReference.child("user");

                chatId = chat.push().getKey();

                HashMap newChatMap = new HashMap();
                newChatMap.put("id", chatId);
                newChatMap.put("users/" + currentUserId, true);
                newChatMap.put("users/" + userId, true);

                // Creating chats table
                chat.child(chatId)
                    .child("info")
                    .updateChildren(newChatMap);

                //Inserting the contact's id in the current user's chat table
                HashMap newUserChatMap = new HashMap();
                newUserChatMap.put(chatId + "/contact", userId);

                user.child(currentUserId)
                    .child("chat")
                    .updateChildren(newUserChatMap);

                //Inserting the current user's id in the contact's chat table
                HashMap newContactChatMap = new HashMap();
                newContactChatMap.put(chatId + "/contact", currentUserId);

                user.child(userId)
                     .child("chat")
                    .updateChildren(newContactChatMap);

                chatExists = true;

                newChatCreated = true;
            }

            if (chatId != null) {
                DatabaseReference newMessageDb = dbReference.child("chat").child(chatId).push();

                Map newMessageMap = new HashMap<>();
                newMessageMap.put("text", editTextMessage);
                newMessageMap.put("creator", currentUserId);

                newMessageDb.updateChildren(newMessageMap);

                messageBodyEditText.setText("");


                if (messageList.isEmpty()) {
                    if (chatExists) {

                        if (ConnectivityHelper.isConnectedToNetwork(this)) {
                                dbReference.child("chat").child(chatId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                                        loadingMessages.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        loadingWarning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        loadingWarning.setText("Loading messages...");



                                        if (dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("info")) {
                                            loadingWarning.setText("Loading messages...");
                                            String text = "";
                                            String creatorId = "";

                                            Object newText = dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue();
                                            Object newCreatorId = dataSnapshot.child("creator").getValue();

                                            if (newText != null) {
                                                text = newText.toString();
                                            }
                                            if (newCreatorId != null) {
                                                creatorId = newCreatorId.toString();
                                            }

                                            String creatorName = "";

                                            if (!creatorId.equals(currentUserId))
                                                creatorName = userName;
                                            else
                                                creatorName = creatorId;

                                            Message message = new Message(dataSnapshot.getKey(), creatorName, text);
                                            messageList.add(message);
                                            messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messagesAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);

                                            loadingMessages.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                            loadingWarning.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                            sendButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                        } else {
                                            loadingMessages.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                            loadingWarning.setText("Messages not found. \nCould not load your messages :/");
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                                        if (dataSnapshot.exists())

                                    }

                                     @Override
                                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                        loadingMessages.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        loadingWarning.setText("Loading cancelled. \nCould not load your messages :/");
                                        Log.d("mymessages", "fetchChatMessages(), onCancelled called.");
                                    }
                                 });

                        } else {
                            lyNoConnection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Log.d("mymessages", "Not connected to network.");
                        }

                    } else {
                        loadingMessages.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        loadingWarning.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        sendButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("mymessages", "chatId = null");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a single code snippet? That way we can rule out anything that is not visible in the code shared.

Comment: Hey, @FrankvanPuffelen. I just added the entire code. I really don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: @IgorGreccoLacourt have you checked the results after putting the `addChildEventLIstener` outside the `onclickLIstener` of the button?. Moreover, `updateChildren` is an async method so use `onSuccessListener` or `onFailureLIstener` with it and put the code below each occurrence of it inside the `onSuccessLIstener`.

Comment: Just tested. Not working even outside the onClick.

Comment: Could it be a Firebase bug?